# RecyclerView OnClickListener only applying logic to final entry and nothing else

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter, which assigns an `OnClickListener` in the `onBindViewHolder`. I have also implemented a `Listener` so that I can handle the data in the corresponding `Fragment`.

Each `CardView` has one `Checkbox` and four subsequent `RadioButtons`. My logic for the `OnClickListener` is as follows:

```
public View.OnClickListener recordData(final ViewHolder holder) {
    View.OnClickListener radioOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (listener != null) {
                int id = view.getId();
                listener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), id);
            }
            if (view.getId() == R.id.checkbox) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "CHECKBOX CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                radioButton1.setClickable(false);
                radioButton1.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    };
    return radioOnClickListener;
}
```

This code has zero impact on any of the entries in the `RecyclerView` apart from the very last one, which works as I would like:

If the `CheckBox` is clicked, the `RadioButtons` should be disabled.

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: Share the screenshot of your screen, how the layout look like. accordingly we can look into the problem. Also share the adapter class and activity from where you calling the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To disable view you need to change the state of the view using method `setEnabled`

below code should solve your issue

```
radioButton1.setEnabled(false);
```